# embed tag src attribute prepends unsafe: in ember js

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, ember-cli, embed-tag

I am trying to use an embed tag and provided a dynamic url for the src attribute

```
<embed src="{{mediaUrl}}" type="{{mimeType}}"  />
```

But when the page is opened I get

```
<embed src="unsafe:abc/def.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
```

- I changed permissions of CSP including media-src, child-src, etc
- I gave complete permissions(*)
- I removed all permissions
- Finally I removed "ember-cli-content-security-policy" altogether even then the prepending of unsafe: could not be avoided.

Removing "ember-cli-content-security-policy" however did not block the url anymore but the url was still prepended with unsafe and because of which the video was not loaded

What else I tried:

- Used a ember component with tag as embed and src and type attribute-binded and used html.safestring. Result: unsafe: was still prepended
- Added the url to the src attribute after component was rendered(did not show video even though unsafe: was not prepended because I believe embed src tag cannot be changed)
- Added the entire  after component was rended and now it worked.

But this is not something I want, I want it to be part of template and not inserted dynamically

Comment: Have you tried `src={{mediaUrl}}` instead of `src="{{mediaUrl}}"`?

Comment: Yeah tried that, didn help

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by using this helper :

```
// app/helpers/safe-string.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function safeString(value) {
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe(value)
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(safeString);
```

You can now do :

```
<embed src="{{safe-string mediaUrl}}" type="{{mimeType}}"  />
```